# How to configure uiscrollview to load data, when it reaches the bottom point

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, triggers

I am making an application, just like [Instagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram), [Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28social_network%29), etc. I need to know, trigger point, where, if the user scrolls to the bottom point and when it bounces, I need to make some calls. How do I get that trigger point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the UIScrollviewDelegate methods: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

You probably want to look at `– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` and `– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` and then inside those methods check the current visible rect of the scrollview using `scrollView.bounds` to find out if the user has scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: okay, checking bounds of scrollview is the key, but i have read somewhere you need to take care of insets also, how to do that. Bcz data will be loaded once user makes scroll view bounce at the bottom ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below code. It may help you.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 60.0, 0.0);

    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height, scrollView.frame.size.width, 160.0) animated:YES];

    if ([scrollView viewWithTag:5000])
    {
        UIView *view = (UIView*)[scrollView viewWithTag:5000];
        [view removeFromSuperview], view = nil;
    }

    UIView *viewloader = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, scrollView.contentSize.height, scrollView.contentSize.width, 160.0)] autorelease];
    viewloader.tag = 5000;

    UILabel *lblloader = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, scrollView.frame.size.width-0.0, 60.0)] autorelease];
    lblloader.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblloader.tag = 550;
    lblloader.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblloader.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lblloader.text = @"Click to load more data.";
    [viewloader addSubview:lblloader];
    viewloader.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    UIButton *btnLoad = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnLoad.frame = lblloader.frame;
    btnLoad.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [btnLoad addTarget:self action:@selector(callForMoreData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewloader addSubview:btnLoad];

    [scrollView addSubview:viewloader];
}
```